# Iterate over json atributes to form table in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code in react:

```
var GridTable = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        var rows = [];
        var headers = [];
        this.props.movies.forEach(function(movie){
            headers.push(<GridHeaders movie={movie} key={movie.id}/>);
            rows.push(<GridRows movie={movie} key={movie.id}/>);
        });
        return(
            <table>
                <thead>{headers}</thead>
                <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }
});
var GridHeaders = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return(<tr><th>{this.props.movie.key}</th></tr>);
    }
});
var GridRows = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return(
            <tr>
                <td>{this.props.movie.id}</td>
                <td>{this.props.movie.category}</td>
                <td>{this.props.movie.title}</td>
                <td>{this.props.movie.director}</td>
                <td>{this.props.movie.year}</td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
});
var MovieGrid = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return(
            <GridTable movies={this.props.movies}/>
        );
    }
});
var MOVIES = [
    {
        "id": 1388534400000,
        "category": "SciFi",
        "title": "Star Wars: The Force Awakens",
        "director": "J.J. Abrams",
        "year": 2015
    },
    {
        "id": 1420070400000,
        "category": "Horror",
        "title": "The Shining",
        "director": "Stanley Kubrick",
        "year": 1980
    }
];
ReactDOM.render(
    <MovieGrid movies={MOVIES}/>,
    document.getElementById("content")
);
```

What I would like to do is iterate over the json and list the attributes as headers in `GridHeaders` to dynamically create the table. I want to avoid specifying the values so the data can be anything. I would like to do the same for GridRows instead of specifying the values I want to print as well so I can again build a table dynamically without worrying about breaking the table. How can I do this in React?

I'm thinking it is going to be something like regular javascript where I would do something like

```
for(i=0; i < movies.length; i++)
```

But I'm not sure how to do this in this instance with React and json.

Comment: Are you asking how to generalize your `Grid*` components so that they aren't Movie specific?

Comment: Basically, yeah I guess, but more specifically it's around the mindset that if I start returning a new attribute value pair in MOVIES that it would display in the table without me having to adjust anything else except the json itself. For example, I add `"rating": ""` as an attribute it will automatically display without adding it in specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to make your headers and rows more dynamic. Get the first item in `movies` and pull the `Object.keys` from it (to use as your headers). Dynamically generate your headers based on the keys. Pass those keys and the `movie` to `GridRows` and display each property in `keys`. I haven't tested this, but it would look something like this:

```
var GridTable = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        var rows = [];
        var headers = [];
        var first = this.props.movies[0];
        // get the property names of the first item to use as headers
        var keys = Object.keys(first);

        return(
            <table>
                <thead>
                    {keys.map(function(title) {
                        return <GridHeaders key={title} title={title} />
                    })}
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {this.props.movies.map(function(movie) {
                        // pass the keys to display values stored at each
                        return <GridRows movie={movie} keys={keys} />
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }
});
var GridHeaders = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        var capitalizedProperty = this.props.title[0].toUpperCase() + this.props.title.slice(1);
        return(<tr><th>{capitalizedProperty}</th></tr>);
    }
});
var GridRows = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return(
            <tr>
                {this.props.keys.map(function(key) {
                    return <td>{this.props.movie[key]}</td>;
                })}
            </tr>
        );
    }
});
```

Note that this doesn't account for properties with an underscore `movie_title`, but you could just make capitalize a more complete function, split on space and map that same logic over the property to produce `Movie Title`

Comment: A couple of tweaks and this worked perfectly. Thanks.